# Reverse Proxy on a Lotus Domino Server?

Tags: reverse-proxy, ibm-domino

Can Lotus Domino be setup as a reverse proxy server?  I have 1 Domino server (web facing) which I would like to configure as a reverse proxy server for an IIS application running on another server?

Is this possible, or do we need to use an apache (or another) web server to do this?

I have checked the IBM docco - they speak about it for iNotes however I do not think it's the same thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you wish to do that via iNotes/DWA then this can be done as mentioned here:
[How to Configure a Reverse Proxy server for iNotes and Sametime Proxy Integration](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/dominowiki.nsf/dx/How_to_Configure_a_Reverse_Proxy_server_for_iNotes_and_Sametime_Proxy_Integration#Apache+Server+Configuration)
And here is a howto from 2008 but the basics should be the same:
[Setup Reverse Proxy with Apache for Lotus Notes Webmail](http://djitz.com/guides/setup-reverse-proxy-with-apache-for-lotus-notes-webmail/)
Please read also this one:
[Configuring iNotes Web Access with a WebSphere Edge reverse proxy server](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/lotus/library/ls-Configuring_IWA_Edge_ReverseProxy/)

However from home IBM Lotus Domino couldn´t act as a Reverse Proxy.

Comment: Thanks - I am looking to do this between servers and not webmail, so I have my answer.  Will look at using another web server for the reverse proxy.  Ta